# xcode localization - not all translation imported

Tags: xcode, localization

I have some weird issues when importing xliff files. Some of both storyboard strings and Strings from my code are not imported, even tho they are in the xliff file.

Her are my xliff:

```
 <body>
        <trans-unit id="Athenticate for login">
            <source>Athenticate for login</source>
            <note>No comment provided by engineer.</note>
            <target>Autentisering for innlogging</target>
        </trans-unit>
        <trans-unit id="Attempts left: ">
            <source>Attempts left:</source>
            <note>No comment provided by engineer.</note>
            <target>Forsøk igjen: </target>
        </trans-unit>
        <trans-unit id="Wrong PIN-code. Try again">
            <source>Wrong PIN-code. Try again</source>
            <note>Message displayed when user enter wrong PIN-code</note>
            <target>Feil PIN kode. Forsøk igjen</target>
        </trans-unit>
    </body>
```

and here ar my localizable.strings

```
/* No comment provided by engineer. */
"Athenticate for login" = "Autentisering for innlogging";

/* Message displayed when user enter wrong PIN-code */
"Wrong PIN-code. Try again" = "Feil PIN kode. Forsøk igjen";
```

as you can see, the "Attempts left" are left out....

anybody have any ide why? (also some strings from the storyboard are left out)

Thanx..

Answer (score 2):

The problem could be that in your XLIFF the ID and the source text for 'Attempts left' are different: the ID has a trailing space, the source text already ends after the colon. Try adding a space to the XLIFF source content and see if the import works then.